# Pass values to the state from formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I use formik for forms in my react app.

```
class myComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      inputData: {}
    }
  }

render() {
  return(
    <Formik>{({ errors, handleChange, values }) => (
      console.log(values);
      <Field type="text" name="address" onChange={handleChange} />
   )}
   </Formik>
  )
}
}
```

The question: how i can pass values to the state?

Comment: you can use the custom onchange method and the set it to state

Answer (score 2):

I think the recommended best practice is to only use Formik state in order to avoid any side effects of having the state stored in 2 locations (Formik + the component state). I was also looking to achieve what you wanted and found the following component - https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik-effect - that will let you decorate the `handleChange` function. However after reading the README for this component I decided to only use the Formik state and pass it's values to any function that require values within that state.

To pass the values to a function I used the following pattern:

```
class Example extends Component {
    handleValues(values) {
        // Do something with values
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Formik>
                ({values}) => {<button onClick={() => this.handleValues(values)}>Do something</button>}
            </Formik>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a handleChange method on your class component as bellow:

```
class myComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      inputData: {}
    }
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
     this.setState({
       inputData: event.target.value
     });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Formik>
      {({ errors, handleChange, values }) => {
          console.log(values);
          return(
            <Field type="text" name="address" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          );
      }}
     </Formik>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is bad solution for my case, cause if i change handleChange method then i will need to define validation func. There are a lot of forms in my app so i need only one default validation func

Comment: really there is no such method to pass values to the state? or just out from the Formik

Comment: Well, for validation you can use the Yup library as seen in the Formik examples, for me, it's the easiest way to validate inputs. Because the Formik only pass the values on the `values` attribute in the children as function, is the only way to get the values to validate. Using the `onChange` method is a better practice because you can validate when the user alter the input, turning the validation messages real-time for better ux. Try using the Yup on the Formik as seen on [here](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/validation#docsNav). Or you can use the validation on `onSubmit` too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the state changes as they are entered, then I would say the best option would be to use the `onSubmit` function to update your state. This also means it will have passed validation before the state has been updated. It sounds like you have a default validation function so you could also add the `validate` prop and use that to call your validator.

```js
class myComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      inputData: {}
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Formik
        initialValues={values}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          // Set updated state here
        }}
        render={({
            submitForm
          }) => (
          <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
            <Field type="text" name="address" onChange={handleChange} />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        )}
      />
    )
  }
}
```